# Batch script - close Cmd.exe window and restart

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd, restart

I have a batch file script which starts a program (bat) and after X seconds the batch script is close the program (exe) and **restart** it.

This is my code:

```
:loop
start "1.bat" "C:\1\1.bat"
Timeout 10
taskkill /f /im program.exe
goto loop
```

If the program is ending, I want that the Cmd.exe window closes, but only the "1.bat" window should be closed. I can't find a specified cmd window for my "1.bat" process in the task manager to close it.

If I close the **programm.exe** with **&& exit** the batch doesn't restart!

Comment: What is in `1.bat`? Why can you not add `exit` at the end of `1.bat` or use another `TIMEOUT`?

Answer (score 0):

You can do one of two things.

1 - If you have access to `1.bat` (i.e. its not readonly or is not actually an .exe), then add `exit` after it runs the `program.exe`.

2 - Otherwise if you cannot modify `1.bat` for whatever reason, you may need to add the following command line:

```
taskkill /FI "IMAGENAME eq cmd.exe" /FI "WINDOWTITLE eq 1.bat"
```

So your batch script will look as follows:

```
:loop
start "1.bat" "C:\1\1.bat"
Timeout 10
taskkill /f /im program.exe
taskkill /FI "IMAGENAME eq cmd.exe" /FI "WINDOWTITLE eq 1.bat"
goto loop
```

Or similar. Basically `/FI` is the filter switch and you can specify to filter based on the "IMAGENAME" (which **eq**uals "cmd.exe") and "WINDOWTITLE" (which **eq**uals "1.bat")

Comment: IMAGENAME = name in taskmanager? WINDOWTITLE = title in the 1.bat file?

Comment: Yes that is correct, you can test it out by running `tasklist`.
For more information and examples, you can run `tasklist /?`